# How do I disable the password autofill in MacOS app

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I have an NSSecureTextField field in my MacOS app. I want to disable the password autofill button from coming up (the "Passwords..." button). I've seen posts about doing it in iOS, but haven't seen anything on Mac OS. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: "I want to disable the password autofill button from coming up" Please don't.

Comment: Why not? You can do it in iOS. There is a potential bug in the OS where this button will show up on the screen in a random place even though my app is hidden. I can't figure out why, so I just want to turn that off completely.

Comment: Because it's a bad UX. People are increasingly using password managers. Going out of your way to disable features that work "for free" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Makes sense not to do it. Better to fix the actual display issue you are having.

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour inside my own password manager app. It is really annoying that Apple don't provide an opt-out mechanism for situations like this. I actually have a couple of NSSecureTextFields and they don't all behave the same way. So some undocumented heuristics are at play.

Comment: The autofill behaviour seems to apply to the first visible `NSSecureTextField` in a `window`. No labels are required, and hiding it excludes it from consideration. I also note that `NSSecureTextField`s within a `sheet` do not have this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to disable password autofill, due to the current default behaviour of showing the autofill button on the first `NSSecureTextField` in a window. But it is a kludge.

I find that if you create a dummy `NSSecureTextField` above the field of concern, and hide it behind another pre-existing field, you can avoid the autofill button appearing. I set this dummy field with `NSTextContentTypeOneTimeCode`.

Note this only works if the dummy `NSSecureTextField` is in the key view loop, so hiding it, or setting `refusesFirstResponder` doesn't help. This also means you need to handle the case where the end user is tabbing from field to field, so as to skip the dummy field.

The focus skipping can be achieved by detecting the completion of editing of the previous field (`controlTextDidEndEditing:`) and changing the focus if and only if the focus is on the dummy field.

All a bit complex for something that could be simply solved with an appropriate `NSTextContentType`!

Comment: BTW, remember this is in the context of a password manager app. So the default behaviour makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Michael Rourke is right - using autofill in cocoa apps causes many problems. If for example I develop an app with a native register screen, user will see the autofill provider which propose existed passwords instead to offer a new one. It's only the one way to hide provider - oneTimeCode. But user could get an empty transparent pop-up (I really think we can find workarounds to hide it, eg use window.makeFirstResponder(textField)) and it's not the most big problem.

As for me the biggest problem is an inability to save new credentials to the icloud keychain and link it with your web domain (But I could be wrong:) ). It is strange to create a password in the application without the possibility of its subsequent use when logging in.

I think It's a cause why apple didn't add a new password to the Big Sure - may be they have some strange problems with creating new record to the keychain using cocoa autofill.

In Zeplin app guys use such workaround as a native login and website registration - so safari creates a record in the keychain, app uses auto fill to login.

I'm pretty sure they'll add a new password in the next versions of the mac os, but it would be better if they finish this feature completely and then release it. They just killed the ability to use it normally in the next version of Mac OS because previous versions (like the current Big Sur) support it poorly.

PS
If a user has a lot of passwords from the current domain and he quickly drives in a password, then there is a high probability of an emergency disconnection of the provider (pop-up).

Comment: And also we can use Mac Catalyst))

Answer (score 1):

After some reverse-engineering, I've found that the following subclass will disable the autofill behavior:

```objectivec
@interface NoAutofillSecureTextField : NSSecureTextField
@end
@implementation NoAutofillSecureTextField
- (BOOL)_isPasswordAutofillEnabled
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: Awesome, the least hacky solution so far and works well.

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: I don't fully remember, but I think I used LLDB to see which methods were called and then looked for ones with relevant names.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "least hacky". Apple won't accept references to non-public  APIs in App store submissions. For good reason. The API could change. But for private use I guess there isn't much risk.

Answer (score 0):

### Note: This answer applies to iOS and UIKit, not macOS

I agree with Alexander, please don't :)

But if you must, it would stop from offering autofill by setting the fields `UITextContentType` Value property to either `.newPassword` or `.oneTimeCode` as [described here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view).

Comment: Would that be a good solution? If it is neither a new password nor one-time code field, then why hack it in this way. Better leave the functionality as is and explore the bug more for a real fix.

Comment: Wouldn't .newPassword offer to generate a new password, and oneTimeCode try to auto-fill from the last SMS message with a code?

Comment: Yes true true it's not a newPassword or oneTimeCode but there doesn't seem to be a way to modify properties of the content type. But it sort of does what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Unfortunately .newPassword isn't available with Appkit, only UIKit. I've tried .oneTimeCode but this causes different problems (a large empty transparent pop-up window appears).